# I have A Mongoose Error Related To Booleans

Tags: javascript, mongodb, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and using mongodb and I have a bool value but whenever I run a economic command, that bool value is set from false to true. I don't want it to be set to true but idk whats causing it to be true. Heres my code.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const colors = require('../../colors.json');
const user = require('../../models/user');
const User = require('../../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ms = require('parse-ms');

module.exports = {
 name: 'beg',
 description:
  'This command can only be used once every 5 hours and gives you $50.',
 category: 'economy',
 usage: 'beg',
 aliases: [],
 run: async (client, message, args) => {
  let reward = 50;
  let timeout = 18000000;

  const S = new MessageEmbed();
  S.setAuthor(message.author.username);
  S.setColor(colors.green);
  S.setDescription(`Here, take $${reward}!`);
  S.setFooter(
   message.author.username,
   message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 })
  );
  S.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL());
  S.setTimestamp();
  S.setTitle('Beg!');

  User.findOne(
   {
    userID: message.author.id,
   },
   async (err, user) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    if (!user) {
     const newUser = new User({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      userID: message.author.id,
      username: message.author.username,
      lb: 'all',
      money: 0,
      deposited: 0,
      iq: 0,
      job: 'None',
      daily: 0,
      beg: 0,
      work: 0,
      aq: 0,
      counteraq: 0,
      counterw: 0,
      reputation: 0,
      banked: 0,
      badge: 0,
      charm: 0,
      ring: 0,
      necklace: 0,
      penguin: 'None',
      fish: 0,
      melon: 0,
      orange: 0,
      meat: 0,
      chocolate: 0,
      neckact: false,
      charmact: false,
      badgeact: false,
      ringact: false,
      muteCount: 0,
      warnCount: 0,
      kickCount: 0,
      banCount: 0,
     });
     newUser
      .save()
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
     const sentBeg = await message.channel.send({ embed: S });
    } else {
     if (timeout - (Date.now() - user.beg) > 0) {
      let cdt = ms(timeout - (Date.now() - user.beg));

      const cd = new MessageEmbed();
      cd.setAuthor(message.author.username);
      cd.setColor(colors.red);
      cd.setDescription(
       `Please stop begging! It's quite selfish! Please wait at least: ${cdt.hours}h, ${cdt.minutes}m and ${cdt.seconds}s.`
      );
      cd.setFooter(
       message.author.username,
       message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 512 })
      );
      cd.setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL());
      cd.setTimestamp();
      cd.setTitle('Stop Begging!');
      const sentCD = await message.channel.send({ embed: cd });
     } else {
      if ((user.ringact = true)) {
       user.beg /= timeout;
       user.money += reward;
       user.save().catch((err) => console.error(err));
       message.channel.send(S);
      } else if ((user.ringact = false)) {
       user.money += reward;
       user.beg = Date.now();
       user.save().catch((err) => console.error(err));
       message.channel.send(S);
      }
     }
    }
   }
  );
 },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has a quite simple fix. You have defined your `if` statements wrong. To check if one value equals another value, you use either `bar == foo` or `bar === foo` (the difference between the two approaches [can be found here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#:%7E:text=triple%20equals%20(%20%3D%3D%3D%20)%20will%20do,types%20differ%2C%20false%20is%20returned.)).

However, you use a single equals sign in your `if` statement which is used to assign a value to a variable. Here's how to fix your code:

Change the following lines:

```js
if (user.ringact = true) {
  //...
} else if (user.ringact = false) {
  //...
}
```

To this:

```js
if (user.ringact === true) {
  //...
} else if (user.ringact === false) {
  //...
}
```

---

*As a little bonus, that code can be shortened to the following:*

```js
if (user.ringact) {
  //...
} else {
  //...
}
```

Or if you want to shorten that whole part of code even more, you can use this (which makes use of the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)):

```js
if (timeout - (Date.now() - user.beg) > 0) {
  //...
} else {
  user.beg = user.ringact ? user.beg / timeout : Date.now();
  user.money += reward;
  user.save().catch(err => console.error(err));
  message.channel.send(S);
}
```